# Php countdown script

Tags: php

I'am trying to make a countdown script using PHP. I have successfully made the first part, where I count down from 72. What's causing me trouble is to find out how to count down in minutes when `$hours < 1`.

Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db = mysql_select_db('time');

$sql = "SELECT time FROM timeanddate";

$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);


$start_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row['time']));

$current_time = date("H:i:s");

function dateDiff($start, $end) {

 $start_ts = strtotime($start);

 $end_ts = strtotime($end);

 $diff = $end_ts - $start_ts;

 return round($diff / 3600);

}

$count = dateDiff($row['time'], $current_time);

$hours = 72;

$hours_left = $hours - $count;

echo $hours_left . " Hours back <br />";
```

Comment: Unless I'm not getting it. I think your confusing server side, with client side. You need to send the latest time from php to javascript, so the javascript can dynamically change the seconds as you are watching. It is impossible to make PHP count down.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply by 60. For example, 0.5 hours * 60 = 30 minutes:

```
if($hours_left > 1) {
    echo $hours_left . " Hours left <br />";
} else if() {
    echo "1 Hour left<br />";
} else {
    echo ceil($hours_left * 60) . " Minutes left";
}
```

Comment: Hey bfavaretto, it will not count down. like 60min, 59min, 58min... and so one. I will just be 60min. for one hour?